# How to fix LocationManager crashing app on initialization

Tags: java, android

I have some code that uses LocationManager to find the location via GPS. When ever I try to run it on my phone (a Alcatel OneTouch Fierce XL), I immediately get the notification "Unfortunately (name of my app) has stopped". This error only occurs when location services is enabled on the smartphone on the app runs smoothly otherwise.

I've tried any sample code I can get to work and I have the same outcome.

Here's my code:

Initializing the GPS:

```
 locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);
```

Methods I use:

```
 //Location stuff
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        try {
            wait(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","disable");
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.eas, PID: 11330
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eas/com.example.eas.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.eas.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2427)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:735)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.eas.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener
    at com.example.eas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6036)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2427) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:735)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.eas.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener
```

It would appear to be coming from:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);
```

`this` (which would appear to be your activity) does not implement the `LocationListener` interface. Add that interface and make sure that you have implemented all the methods required by that interface.

You can learn more about Java interfaces in [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).